# how to check a string for a special character in Java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JAVA: check a string if there is a special character in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795402/java-check-a-string-if-there-is-a-special-character-in-it)

I'm testing a method that transforms a string into another string except it preservers all special characters (non alpha-numeric).

So I'm looking to test the output of this method to ensure it actually preserves these characters.
I know this calls for use of `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes but not sure how.
I think I need to build a format template, compile it with `Pattern` and then use it with `Matcher` with the output string of my test method
.
So I'll build the format template character by character. For digits and characters, I can use IsLetter and IsDigit of Character class and insert `"\\d"` for digit in my template.
Not sure what I should use for letters and special characters.

Any Ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Define "preserves" - does that mean `"abc!d." --> "   ! ."` or `"abc!d." --> "!."` or something else? Please give sample input and output data

Answer (score 0):

You should write pattern that replaces all forbidden characters to nothing and use `String.replaceAll()` method. Something like the following:

`str = str.replaceAll("[^\\w_\\d]", "");`

Comment: fyi, `\w` *includes* `_` and `\d`, so simply `[^\\w]` is the same as your regex