# How to determine if a String has non-alphanumeric characters?

Tags: java, string, character, alphanumeric

I need a method that can tell me if a String has non alphanumeric characters.

For example if the String is "abcdef?" or "abcdefà", the method must return true.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795402/java-check-a-string-if-there-is-a-special-character-in-it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241690/regex-for-checking-if-a-string-is-strictly-alphanumeric

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Using Apache Commons Lang:

```
!StringUtils.isAlphanumeric(String)
```

Alternativly iterate over String's characters and check with:

```
!Character.isLetterOrDigit(char)
```

You've still one problem left:
Your example string "abcdefà" is alphanumeric, since `à` is a letter. But I think you want it to be considered non-alphanumeric, right?!

So you may want to use regular expression instead:

```
String s = "abcdefà";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");
boolean hasSpecialChar = p.matcher(s).find();
```

Comment: I would like to avoid importing external libraries if not strictly necessary. And yes: I want à to be considered as non alphanumeric.

Comment: a *side note:* unrelated but just to remind ```StringUtils.isAlphaNumeric("abc");``` returns ```true``` if the str contains only alphabets.

Answer (score 29):

One approach is to do that using the String class itself.
Let's say that your string is something like that:

```
String s = "some text";
boolean hasNonAlpha = s.matches("^.*[^a-zA-Z0-9 ].*$");
```

one other is to use an external library, such as Apache commons:

```
String s = "some text";
boolean hasNonAlpha = !StringUtils.isAlphanumeric(s);
```

Comment: +1: regex is here the winner I think since the OP does not really want to check for alphanumeric characters. He wants sth. like `hasSpecialCharacters(String)` with his own definition of "special".

Comment: That won't quite work: `String.matches(...)` in Java checks if the regex matches the *whole* string.

Comment: `boolean hasNonAlpha = ! … ^[A-Za-z0-9 ]*$`

Answer (score 6):

You have to go through each character in the String and check `Character.isDigit(char);` or `Character.isletter(char);`

Alternatively, you can use regex.

Comment: For example, "-1234" is a number, not an alphanumeric string. But your logic Character.isDigit will return false for "-". :(

Comment: I think it is Character.isLetter not Character.isletter

Answer (score 4):

Use this function to check if a string is alphanumeric:

```
public boolean isAlphanumeric(String str)
{
    char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
    for(char c:charArray)
    {
        if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(c))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

It saves having to import external libraries and the code can easily be modified should you later wish to perform different validation checks on strings.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use the Apache Commons library, then Commons-Lang `StringUtils` has a method called `isAlphanumeric()` that does what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`string.matches("^\\W*$");` should do what you want, but it does not include whitespace. `string.matches("^(?:\\W|\\s)*$");` does match whitespace as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use isLetter(char c) static method of Character class in Java.lang .

```
public boolean isAlpha(String s) {
    char[] charArr = s.toCharArray();

    for(char c : charArr) {
        if(!Character.isLetter(c)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though it won't work for numbers, you can check if the lowercase and uppercase values are same or not, For non-alphabetic characters they will be same, You should check for number before this for better usability

Answer (score 0):

I had to check a string contains at least 1 letter and 1 digit - my solution below

```
/**
 * <p>Checks if the String contains both letters and digits.</p>
 *
 * <p>{@code null} will return {@code false}.
 * An empty String str.isEmpty() will return {@code false}.</p>
 *
 * @param str the String to check, may be null
 * @return {@code true} if only contains letters and digits,
 * and is non-null or not empty
 */
public static boolean isAlphaAndNumeric(String str) {
    if (str == null || str.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");
    boolean containsSpecialChars = !pattern.matcher(str).matches();
    if (containsSpecialChars) {
        return false;
    }
    
    boolean containsLetter = false;
    boolean containsDigit = false;
    char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < chars.length) {
        if (Character.isLetter(chars[i])) {
            containsLetter = true;
        }
        if (Character.isDigit(chars[i])) {
            containsDigit = true;
        }
        i++;
        if (containsDigit && containsLetter) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```