# android check if string contains characters other than 0-9

Tags: android, string, parsing, crash

I am creating an app for counting points in games. This app has a edittext component. I want to check if the string retrieved from the edit text contains characters other than 0-9. This is because my app contains a integer.parse function wich crashes if characters other than 0-9 is inputed. All help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248277/how-to-determine-if-a-string-has-non-alphanumeric-characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to notify the user of an invalid character then you can wrap it in a `try/catch` and act accordingly

```
try
{
    int someInt = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
    // other code
}
catch (NumberFormatException e)
{
    // notify user with Toast, alert, etc...
}
```

You also can use a [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to look for the characters you want/don't want depending on your needs.

**Just to be clear** in case my code comment wasn't, I am suggesting that you do something with the exception and notify the user. Don't catch it and let it sit

Comment: bad approch you should not do that!

Comment: Yup, and this is a good thing to do regardless. Another safety net you could add is the `android:digits` attribute on your EditText. Set it to `android:digits="0123456789"`. This will restrict entry to only those characters.

Comment: @hasan Why is it bad?

Comment: @kcoppock yes, thank you. I should have mentioned that it should typically be used in parsing.

Comment: Yeah, there's nothing bad about catching an exception. Catching and disregarding, sure, but there's absolutely nothing wrong with this approach.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String str)
{
    for (char c : str.toCharArray())
    {
        if (!Character.isDigit(c)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

OR

```
public boolean isNumeric(String s) {  
    return s.matches("[-+]?\\d*\\.?\\d+");  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can setup edittext as integer numbers only, so in your layout put

`android:inputType="number"`

It will set to integer numbers only in edit text.

All possible types here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType

Then you can test with regular expression or/and catch exception when parsing.
Regular expression would be:

`"string".matches("\\d+") // true when numbers only, false otherwise`

Reference here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html