# Get EditText value on button click and do math with that value?

Tags: java, android

I am creating a program that is supposed to
1. Get the value of a spinner, either "Fahrenheit to Celsius" or "Celsius to Fahrenheit"
2. Get the value of `EditText` and convert it into an integer
3. Multiply that integer by 100
4. Set `TextView` text as that integer.
The problem is that I'm getting `java.lang.NumberFormatException`.
Here is my code:

```
 package org.infinitech.degreescalculator.app;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    public class MainActivity extends Activity{
        public Spinner spinner;
        public String selectedItem;
        public EditText input;
        public Button button;
        public String inputValue=findViewById(R.id.input).toString();
        public Integer num=Integer.parseInt(inputValue);
        public String num2;
        public TextView answer;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.options);
            selectedItem=(String)spinner.getSelectedItem();
            input=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.input);
            button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
            answer=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.answer);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    if(selectedItem.equals("Fahrenheit to Celsius")){
                        num=num*100;
                        num2=num.toString();
                        answer.setText(num2);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main,menu);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Here is my logcat:
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
I fixed it! Here is my new modified code:

```
 package org.infinitech.degreescalculator.app;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.Spinner;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 public class MainActivity extends Activity{
     public Spinner spinner;
     public String selectedItem;
     public EditText input;
     public Integer num;
     public Button button;
     public TextView answer;
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.options);
         selectedItem=(String)spinner.getSelectedItem();
         input=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.input);
         button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
         answer=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.answer);
         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
             public void onClick(View v){
                 if(selectedItem.equals("Fahrenheit to Celsius")){
                     num=Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString())*100;
                     answer.setText(num.toString());
                 }
             }
         });
     }
     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main,menu);
         return true;
     }
     @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
         return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }
 }
```

Comment: where does it tell you the `NullPointerException` is?

Comment: @yate It was `java.lang.NumberFormatException` I put NullPointerException instead.  Fixed.

Comment: [See this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880962/i-would-like-to-set-my-variables-at-the-top-of-my-class-instead-of-in-the-method/18881067#18881067) and [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19988434/android-check-if-string-contains-characters-other-than-0-9/19988499#19988499)

Answer (score 1):

Remove below lines from your `Activity`

```
   public String inputValue=findViewById(R.id.input).toString();
   public Integer num=Integer.parseInt(inputValue);
```

and Add in `OnCreate` Method as

```
 String inputValue= input.getText().toString();
 Integer num=Integer.parseInt(inputValue);
```

Because `input EditText` already defined.

And to convert **num** to **String** use `String.valueOf` instead of `.toString()`.So change button Onclick function as

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    if(selectedItem.equals("Fahrenheit to Celsius")){
                        num=num*100;
                        answer.setText(String.valueOf(num));
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Is it working for you? And also Check links that @codeMagic suggested.

Comment: I'm afraid it's still not working.  I am getting `java.lang.NumberFormatException`

Comment: @InfiniTech did you change your code,please post logcat exception also.

Comment: @InfiniTech What is input value,i.e. edittext value. try to chnage your code as I suggested.

Comment: Now it is java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @InfiniTech post logcat exception

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @InfiniTech see my edited answer ,i.e. rewrite onclick function as in my answer.

Comment: @InfiniTech ohh yourself great

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
        public String inputValue=findViewById(R.id.input).toString();
```

as

```
        public String inputValue=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.input).getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

use getText() like so

```
EditText inputView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
String inputValue = inputView.getText().toString();
```

you should do all of this in the onCreate() method