# How to check if all characters in a String are all letters?

Tags: java, string, character

I'm able to separate the words in the sentence but I do not know how to check if a word contains a character other than a letter. You don't have to post an answer just some material I could read to help me.

```
public static void main(String args [])
{
    String sentance;
    String word;
    int index = 1;

    System.out.println("Enter sentance please");
    sentance = EasyIn.getString();

    String[] words = sentance.split(" ");    

    for ( String ss : words ) 
    {
        System.out.println("Word " + index + " is " + ss);
        index++;
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I would do is use `String#matches` and use the regex `[a-zA-Z]+`.

```
String hello = "Hello!";
String hello1 = "Hello";

System.out.println(hello.matches("[a-zA-Z]+"));  // false
System.out.println(hello1.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")); // true
```

---

Another solution is `if (Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i))` inside a loop.

---

Another solution is something like this

```
String set = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
String word = "Hello!";

boolean notLetterFound;
for (char c : word.toCharArray()){  // loop through string as character array
    if (!set.contains(c)){         // if a character is not found in the set
        notLetterfound = true;    // make notLetterFound true and break the loop
        break;                       
    }
}

if (notLetterFound){    // notLetterFound is true, do something
    // do something
}
```

---

I prefer the first answer though, using `String#matches`

Comment: See the thing is I need to check all of the words individually and see if they have a character other than a letter and the output whether its a good word(contains only letters) or a bad word (for example "Hell0" is a bad word)

Comment: In your loop, just use `if (ss.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) { // do something }`.

Answer (score 1):

For more reference goto-> [How to determine if a String has non-alphanumeric characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248277/how-to-determine-if-a-string-has-non-alphanumeric-characters) 
Make the following changes in pattern "[^a-zA-Z^]"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question, but there is the

Character.isAlpha(c);

You would iterate over all characters in your string and check whether they are alphabetic (there are other "isXxxxx" methods in the Character class).

Comment: If I were to enter "Thanks for helping geert3" it would output geert3 is a bad word because it contains a number.

Comment: <then you need the isAlphanum() method, which check for alpha or numeric

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the characters in the word calling `Character.isLetter()`, or maybe check if it matches a regular expression e.g. `[\w]*` (this would match the word only if its contents are all characters).

Answer (score -1):

you can use charector array to do this like..

char[] a=ss.toCharArray();

not you can get the charector at the perticulor index.

with "word "+index+" is "+a[index];