# How to check each of the character inside a string

Tags: java

As I have mentioned on the title above I need to know how to check each of the characters inside a String as follows:

1. check if the string is less than 3 character.
2. check if the string contains digits.
3. check if a single word of string has no vowels.

I've been searching for the exact example but I couldn't find one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if all characters in a String are all letters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569685/how-to-check-if-all-characters-in-a-string-are-all-letters)

Comment: Did you tried anything? Please post some code snippet which you have tried.

Comment: First of all, I'm new in JAVA or programming, in general, I tried to read some examples and other posts but I can't still figure it out because those posts I've read are some kind of advanced codes so I thought of posting here and hoping to get a better explanation and easy methods.

Comment: @HaiderAbdullah check my answer. If it's helpful, just click on the gray tick below my answer's score

Answer (score 1):

Follow those steps:

```
String s = "mystring";
s.length() < 3 // expression which says if it's smaller than 3.
s.matches(".*[0-9].*") //expression which says if there are digits in the string
s.matches("\b[^aeiouAEIOU ]+\b") //expression which says if there are no vovels
```

To check if `yourString` matches all those conditions:

```
if (myString.length() < 3 && myString.matches(".*[0-9].*") 
    && myString.matches("\b[^aeiouAEIOU ]+\b")) {
   //matches all
}
```

Comment: let me try this one and I will get back to you later. thank you very much I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm still fixing my laptop it's hanging I will inform you later after I fix this.

Comment: Hi, I'm having trouble with this line of codes.length() < 3 should I end it with the semi-colon?

Comment: Sir, I'm just getting confused about your code arrangement, mostly this part "s.length() < 3" I used them now and it didn't work. I don't know if I'm just having a problem on how I followed it or you really need to specify it properly. Sorry sir I'm just a starter.

Comment: @HaiderAbdullah I made a typo. Check now. There was a misspelling in the length()