# how to check if string contains only numerics or letters properly? Android

Tags: java, android, string, match

I am trying to set requirements for a certain number that a user requiers to enter(pNumber). pNumber should consist of 2 letters then 6 letters or numbers and finally a number.

I have implemented a method i found here on stackoverflow, but when i enter a number like: "LL^&%JJk9" it still gives me a positive result?
to my understanding .matches checks that a string only consists of the given values?

```
String First = pNumber.substring(0, 2);
String Middle = pNumber.substring(2, 8);
String Last = pNumber.substring(8, 9);

if (First.matches(".*[a-zA-Z].*") && Middle.matches(".*[a-zA-Z0-9].*") && Last.matches(".*[0-9].*")) {
  greenOk.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  nextBtn.setEnabled(true);
} else {
  redCross.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: This should suffice: it is the inverse of your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8248352/503508

Comment: Incidentally, your regexes are probably not what you think they are. They are essentially matching for 1. any character in the first string. 2. any character / digit in the middle string. 3. any digit in the third string.

Comment: [RegExr](http://regexr.com/) is great for learning and testing regex.

Comment: what do you think `.*` means? and `[a-zA-Z]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) for that. There you have methods like [isNumeric](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isNumeric%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) and [isAlphanumeric](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isAlphanumeric%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Or use methods like Character [isDigit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit%28char%29)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
    String input1 = "TYe4r5t12";
    String input2 = "LL^&%JJk9";

    String pattern = "([a-zA-Z]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}[0-9]{1})";

    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

    Matcher m = r.matcher(input1);

    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Valid !!!");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Invalid !!!");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`TextUtils` class has various methods and one of them is given below.

```
TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(string)
```

Answer (score -1):

[This Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8248352/503508) details how to use Apache Commons to solve your problem.

If you are looking for a Regular Expression route of solving your issue, this will likely help you:

```
if(pNumber.matches("[a-zA-Z]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}[0-9]")) {
    greenOk.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    nextBtn.setEnabled(true);
} else {
    redCross.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: The middle 6 characters are letters/numbers and the last character is a number.

Comment: The regular expression is not correct. The requirements state: 2 letters, then 6 letters or digits and finally 1 digit. The pattern you provided matches 2 letters, 6 digits and 1 letter.