# replaceAll regex excluding certain occurrences

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to parse certain addresses, and I'd like to remove out the special characters except the / in s/o  | S/O | d/o | D/O | w/O etc.

So, lets say I have a string. Something like.

```
@Jane Doe.
W/O John Doe.
House #250, 
Campbell & Jack ^Street,
\Random * State,  Nowhere.
```

What sort of regex would I use in

```
String parsedString = addressString.replaceAll(regex,"");
```

so that parsedString would have the output.

```
Jane Doe
W/O John Doe
House 250
Campbell Jack Street
Random  State,  Nowhere
```

(I'm replacing @ , . # ^ & / (except in W/O) )

Comment: humm Offtopic: but may help to [clarify some things...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsJyw.jpg)

Comment: Where's your regex?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248277/how-to-determine-if-a-string-has-non-alphanumeric-characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this pattern with the option case insensitive:

```
String pat = "[@#&^*/.,](?i)(?<![wds]/(?=o))";
```

details:

```
[@#&^*/.,]  # characters you want to remove
(?i)       # switch the case insensitive flag
(?<!       # negative lookbehind: not preceded by
    [wds]/ # w or d or s and a slash
    (?=o)  # lookahead: followed by a o
)
```

Comment: Did you tested it before you posted?

Comment: Your updated comment works exactly as I want it to. :)
Here's me testing it a bit, incase anyone is interested.
https://ideone.com/MzWWZW