# Determine a special character through Charset

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to check, if my character is a special symbol or not using standard Charset (for now, I've implemented it through regex check of `[^a-zA-Z0-9 ])`. Is it possible to check through Charset class in Java or Kotlin?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if a character is a special character in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12885821/checking-if-a-character-is-a-special-character-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no dedicated function defined on Java's [`Charset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) to determine if it contains special characters.

Using a regular expression is completely fine but you could do it like this as well:

```
fun Char.isSpecialChar() = toLowerCase() !in 'a'..'z' && !isDigit() && !isWhitespace()

fun CharSequence.containsSpecialChars() = any(Char::isSpecialChar)

'H'.isSpecialChar() // false
'&'.isSpecialChar() // true
"Hello World".containsSpecialChars() // false
"Hello & Goodbye".containsSpecialChars() // true
```

This is a Kotlin solution, so if you have a Java [`Charset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) some casting might be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at class `java.lang.Character` static member methods (isDigit, isLetter, isLowerCase, ...)

**Example:**

```
String str = "Hello World 123 !!";
int specials = 0, digits = 0, letters = 0, spaces = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
   char ch = str.charAt(i);
   if (!Character.isDigit(ch) && !Character.isLetter(ch) && !Character.isSpace(ch)) {
      ++specials;
   } else if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
      ++digits;
   } else if (Character.isSpace(ch)) {
      ++spaces;
   } else {
      ++letters;
   }
}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12885821/checking-if-a-character-is-a-special-character-in-java):