# Is there any Java library to provide list of ASCII special characters?

Tags: java, open-source, nlp

Is there any Java library to provide list of ASCII special characters?

Example:

```
[SPACE]   {END}  -  /  |  \  ;  :  ::  #  *  &  ( 
)  >  <  [  ]  {  }  ?  !  ‘  “
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JAVA: check a string if there is a special character in it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795402/java-check-a-string-if-there-is-a-special-character-in-it)

Comment: useful link: [Escape special characters](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?)Id=96

Comment: I want a standard body util class which returns all ASCII special character. If i maintain this list, i need to keep updating my code if changes some in in the list.

Comment: add this in your question/

Comment: how do you define special char? everything that is not a letter or a digit? everything > 127 (ASCII is 7Bit)?

Comment: Marco Forberg: Thanks for the response. Yes, anything other than numbers and digits would be called special characters in my case.

Comment: Grijesh Chauhan: This question is not duplicate of mentioned question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create the list on your own

```
List<Character> specialChars = new ArrayList<Character>();
for(char code = 0; code < 256; code++) {
    if(!Character.isLetterOrDigit(code)) {
        specialChars.add(new Character(code));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create 256 consecutive chars, and keep the 'non-digit' and 'non-letter' if that's what you want:

```
public List<Character> getSpecialChars()
{
    List<Character> specialCharacters = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        Character c = new Character((char) i);
        if (!Character.isDigit(c) && !Character.isLetter(c))
        {
            specialCharacters.add(c);
        }
    }
    return specialCharacters;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the ascii table here:
http://www.asciitable.com/

If you want to use those characters, you can use Chars

Example:

```
Char c = new Char(93);
```

Comment: I think OP wants something  like `isespacialchar(ch)` function

Comment: it is `Chararacter`in java - not `Char`

Comment: I want a standard body util class which returns all ASCII special character.

Comment: I don't know if one already exists, but you can easily make that yourself by using the Char class.