# How to restrict user from entering Special characters in SWT textfield

Tags: java, validation, swt, textfield

I want to restrict user from entering Special characters in SWT text field.
I tried the below code, but it is not working....

```
   txt_Appname.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
    {
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            char chars = e.character;
            if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(chars)) {
                e.doit = false;
                return;
            }
        }
    });
```

can any one give me the working code for restricting special characters in SWT textfield ?

Comment: Does [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795402/java-check-a-string-if-there-is-a-special-character-in-it) helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `VerifyListener`:

```
txt_Appname.addVerifyListener(new VerifyListener() {
  @Override
  public void verifyText(VerifyEvent e) {
      String text = e.text;
      for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
         if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(text.charAt(i)) {
            e.doit = false;
            return;
         }
      }
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, can u please tell how to check using e.text ? am beginner to SWT

Comment: Added example processing