# What do I do if I want to check for a special character in Java using char?

Tags: java, if-statement, char

I want to create a program for checking whether any inputted character is a special character or not. The problem is that I hava no idea what to do: either check for special characters or check for the ASCII value. Can anyone tell me if I can just check for the numerical ASCII value using 'if' statement or if I need to check each special character?

Comment: if only there was an expression you could use on a regular basis to do that... hmmm its a shame really

Comment: special character as in... not [a-zA-Z0-9] ?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Maybe give us some example and clarify what you mean by *special*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JAVA: check a string if there is a special character in it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795402/java-check-a-string-if-there-is-a-special-character-in-it)

Answer (score 5):

You can use regex (Regular Expressions):

```
if (String.valueOf(character).matches("[^a-zA-Z0-9]")) {
    //Your code
}
```

The code in the `if` statement will execute if the character is not alphanumeric. (whitespace will count as a special character.) If you don't want white space to count as a special character, change the string to `"[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]"`.

**Further reading:**

- [JavaDoc for the `matches` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-)
- [An excellent regex tutorial](https://regexone.com)
- [More info about regex in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)
- [A regex builder (pointed out by @Wietlol)](https://regex101.com)

Comment: Maybe add a link to http://www.regex101.com ? its perfectly if you want to build a regular expression

Answer (score 2):

You can use isLetter(char c) and isDigit(char c).  You could do it like this:

```
char c;
//assign c in some way
if(!Character.isLetter(c) && !Character.isDigit(c)) {
    //do something in case of special character
} else {
    //do something for non-special character
}
```

**EDIT:** As pointed out in the comments it may be more viable to use isLetterOrDigit(char c) instead.

**EDIT2:** As ostrichofevil pointed out (which I did not think or know of when i posted the answer) this solution won't restrict "non-special" characters to A-Z, a-z and 0-9, but will include anything that is considered a letter or number in Unicode. This probably makes ostrichofevil's answer a more practical solution in most cases.

Comment: Note that `Character.isLetter` will return true for any Unicode character classified as a letter, not just the letters *a-z* and *A-Z*. The same goes for `isDigit`; there are other characters than *0-9* which are classified as digits.

Comment: use `!Character.isLetterOrDigit(c);` rather than using && operation. However code will return true for `$  _ ` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it in this way :

```
char[] specialCh = {'!','@',']','#','$','%','^','&','*'}; // you can specify all special characters in this array

boolean hasSpecialChar = false;

char current;

for (Character c : specialCh) {
      if (current == c){
          hasSpecialChar = true;
      }
 }
```