# Is there a way to make sure that a certain character is in a string?

Tags: java

I have a BYOL (Build your own Lab) for my Computer Science class. This lab is due in 3 days, and I need a bit of help on one of the parts. I would like to know how to determine if the user has input a special character (@, #, !, *, $, c, %, etc) and I want to know how to close the string if that character is not included in the string. I am using an if...then loop to close strings when the user's input is not in the correct format. (Ex: I asked them to input their SSN, so it must be in the format XXX-XX-XXXX, otherwise it will close the string.) I need to ask them for their E-Mail address and want the answer to include "@". All help is appreciated.

Here is my code, because I do not know how to post it separately.

```
public static void main (String[]args)
   {
   String answer;
   do {
      Scanner word=new Scanner(System.in);
      Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Oh No! It appears that Dwayne \"The Rock\" Johnson has stolen your Credit Card and SSN Info!");
      System.out.print("\nPlease input some information for us to secure your personal Info.");
      System.out.print("\n\nPlease enter your Social Security Number: (XXX-XX-XXXX) ");
      System.out.print("\nPlease be aware that you must input the information in the correct format (Without the parentheses at the begining and end) ");
      String ssn=input.nextLine();
      if (ssn.length()!=11)
         System.out.println("\nYou have entered the incorrect format! (XXX-XX-XXXX)" );
      if (ssn.length()!=11)
         System.exit(0);

      System.out.print("\nPlease enter your Credit Card Number:(XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX) ");
      String ccn=input.nextLine();
      if (ccn.length()!=19)   
         System.out.println("\nYou have entered the incorrect format! (XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX)");
      if (ccn.length()!=19)
         System.exit(0);

      System.out.print("\nPlease enter your Credit Card Expiration Date: (MM/YY) ");
      String exp=word.nextLine();    

      System.out.print("\nPlease enter your CVV (Card Verification Value): (XXX) ");
      String back=word.nextLine();
      if (back.length()!=3)
         System.out.println("\nYou have entered the incorrect format! (XXX)");
      if (back.length()!=3)
         System.exit(0);    

      System.out.print("\nPlease enter your E-Mail Address: ");
      String mail=word.nextLine();

      System.out.print("\nPlease enter your American Phone Number: (+1(XXX) XXX-XXXX) ");
      String phone=word.nextLine();
      if (phone.length()!=16)
         System.out.println("\nYou have entered the incorrect format! (+1(XXX) XXX-XXXX)");
      if (phone.length()!=16)
         System.exit(0);    

      System.out.print("\nPlease enter your home address: ");
      String home=word.nextLine();

      System.out.print("\nPlease enter your First Name: ");
      String name=word.nextLine();

      System.out.print("\nPlease enter your Middle Initial (X): ");
      String mid=word.nextLine();
      if (mid.length()!=1)
         System.out.println("\nYou have entered the incorrect format! (X)");
      if (mid.length()!=1)
         System.exit(0);

      System.out.print("\nPlease enter your Last Name: ");
      String last=word.nextLine();

      System.out.print("\nPlease enter your Date of Birth: (MM/DD/YYYY) ");
      String dob=word.nextLine();
      if (dob.length()!=10)
         System.out.println("\nYou have entered the incorrect format! (MM/DD/YYYY)");
      if (dob.length()!=10)
         System.exit(0);    

      System.out.println("\n\n\t\t\t\tThank you, you have secured your information");
      System.out.println("\nIf you have any comments or concerns, please contact us at these locations:");
      System.out.println("\n\n\t+1(555) 555-5555");
      System.out.println("\n\tgoogleuser@gmail.com");
      System.out.println("\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\tThank you, and have a wonderful day!");
      System.out.println("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tThe Scammer Preventer™ Team");
      System.out.println("\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\tDo you have more information to input? Yes or No: ");
      answer=input.next();
      }
      while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("\n\nYes"));

   }
}
```

Comment: Please only post the part of your code relevant to the question.  What does it mean to "close the string"?

Comment: sorry, (I'm new to Java) I just need to understand how to close the entire program if the email address does not include the "@"

Comment: Also kindly don't post sentences like "This lab is due in 3 days" this is not related to your question, posting like this will not give your question high priority.

Comment: okay, thank you for the advice

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!mail.contains("@")) {
  System.exit(0);
}
```

This answer may also help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1795436/1317559

Comment: Thank You. This helped me a lot.

Comment: No problem, added a link also.